# Avoid re-modelling objects from a base EF Core 3.0 model when inherritting the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, dbcontext

**The goal**

My goal is to create a hierarchy of DbContexts each one residing in different assembly. Whatever  references are required are established correctly so that the C# code compiles successfully.

**The scenario**

Let's say I create a db context, e.g. `DbChild`, inheriting from a base one, say `DbBase`.

The base context has some entities defined in `OnModelCreating()`. A migration for these entities is created and successfully applied to the database, thus the db schema contains the DbBase model mapped.

Needless to say `DbChild` uses the very same connection string and therefore the same database (I tried a number of ways to supply the connection string, the last one specifying it directly in `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("<conection string>");`).

**Actual result**

Creating a migration for the child context, however, includes the base model as part of the child one, which results in duplicate SQL objects in the DB.

**Required result**

A "**clean**" migration including **only** SQL objects (EF entities) from the child context is required.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**PS**: calling `Ignore(...)` in `OnModelCreating()` might be a workaround but it needs everything referenced in `DbBase` to be referenced in `DbChild` which is not an option.

**PS2**: Totally ignoring the base model while create the child one is not an option too - child uses an entity from base as a relationship.

**EDIT**: The snapshot `<ContextName>ModelSnapshot.cs` contains a "copy" of the model which gets updated with each migration. This is where every migration starts up. In complex models, however, it would be much easier, and what is much more important - safe, to have the snapshot file generated programmatically out of the existing database instead of copying, changing namespaces, renaming so as to have the context name reflected etc.

So, the questions may be transformed to "**How to generate database snapshot when applying the first migration?**".

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: As a first action with a new context, execute `Add-Migration PreExisting –IgnoreChanges`. Then start adding specific things to your child context. Only works if the parent model never changes or you add a new ignore-changes migration in the child for each parent change.

Comment: @grek40 It's OK. I was about to write the same thing since I checked it. This is why it was obvious to me. Anyway I deleted this comment, since it does not bring any new value. I think your comment should be the answer of the question - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new derived context, after setting up the DB connection string but before adding any derived types to the context, you should create a migration that saves the snapshot of the pre-existing base context types.

In EF6, this would be done by creating a migration with `Add-Migration PreExisting –IgnoreChanges`. This produces a migration, where the internal model contains an updated snapshot, but the `Up` and `Down` methods of the migration are empty.

I'm not up to date on whether EF Core does support the `-IgnoreChanges` switch currently. According to [What is the equivalent of the -IgnoreChanges switch for entity-framework core in CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53210060/5265292), an alternative is, to manually clear the Up/Down methods after creating a migration.

Only after the first snapshot migration is created, start with adding additional entities to the derived context and creating migrations to add them to the database etc.

Comment: Yes, it seems EF Core (3.0) does not support IgnoreChanges switch. A descendent DbContext with no OnModelCreating should be used to generate the base snapshot migration, then manual cleaning the Up/Down down to {} does the work. Then any new entities can be added as well as a new "clean" migration.